# CVE-2019-14748 but the file is downloaded and open locally - can it be used for XSS?

Tags: xss, file-upload, cve

I'm testing [CVE-2019-14748](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/47224) on an `example.com` with osTicket. I've uploaded a `test.html` with the basic `<script>` and `<img>` XSS payloads which run when a user opens `test.html`. However, in Firefox, when I click on the `test.html` file for viewing, I'm prompted the "Open in/Save as" box and I click "Open in Firefox", which opens the file in another tab but the address is `file:///tmp/mozilla__0/test.html`.

The file is downloaded to and open in a local `file://`, but the process is still initiated by `example.com` Can this still be used for XSS, or is it nullified by the fact that the XSS payload is now in a separate local file?

Answer (score 1):

> The file is downloaded to and open in a local file://, but the process
> is still initiated by example.com Can this still be used for XSS, or
> is it nullified by the fact that the XSS payload is now in a separate
> local file?

No,the XSS payload wont work that way.

also in CVE-2019-14748 the [step to reproduce](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/47224) is from within the osticket portal itself.

> - Login with another user(agent)
> - Now within the User Directory, go to the user under which the payload has been put.
> - The ticket raised with the name mentioned will be shown under the subject category.
> - Scroll down and the file uploaded will be present below.
> - Click on the file, and the payload gets executed which is persistent